# MySQL: use results of a subquery in another subquery?

Tags: mysql

Assume the following tables:

```
TABLE: foo
=========================
| foo_id | fk_id | name |
=========================
| 1      | 100   | A    |
| 2      | 100   | B    |
| 3      | 200   | C    |
| 4      | 200   | D    |
| 5      |       | E    |
| 6      |       | F    |
-------------------------

TABLE: foo_combo
===============================================
| foo_combo_id | parent_foo_id | child_foo_id |
===============================================
| 1            | 5             | 1            |
| 2            | 5             | 2            |
| 3            | 6             | 3            |
| 4            | 6             | 4            |
-----------------------------------------------
```

I need to get all `foo` where `fk_id` is 100 and all `foo` combinations that are made up of `foo` where `fk_id` is 100. Using the sample data provided, I need `fk_id` = 1,2, (these have `fk_id` = 100) and 5 (this is a `foo` made up of `foo` that have `fk_id` = 100).

What should the SQL look like?

EDIT 1:

Two queries I think that need to be combined:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE fk_id = 100
SELECT foo.* FROM foo, foo_combo WHERE foo_combo.child_id IN (SELECT foo_id FROM foo WHERE fk_id = 100) AND foo.foo_id = foo_combo.parent_foo_id ???
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select foo_id from (
  select foo_id, fk_id from foo 
    union all
  select c.parent_foo_id, f.fk_id from foo_combo c inner join foo f on (c.child_foo_id = f.foo_id)
) foo_union where fk_id = 100;
```

That should return something like

```
+--------+
| foo_id |
+--------+
|      1 |
|      2 |
|      5 |
|      5 |
+--------+
```

The 5 is repeated because it matches twice.  If you don't want that, try adding "distinct" -- ugly but serviceable.

Comment: Or that.  :)  There is (or might be) some difference under the hood but the results will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are after:

```
select f.*
from foo f
inner join foo_combo fc on fc.child_foo_id = f.foo_id
where f.fk_id = 100;
```

Though I am unsure whether the column on the `foo_combo` table is `child_foo_id` or `child_id` (the example data and example queries refer to this column differently).

Comment: That won't return the combo IDs.

Comment: Right. I think I need to `UNION`, but somehow reference the results of the first query in the second query.

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie - could you edit your post to make your desired result a little clearer, please? It sounds as though you need 3 rows consisting of foo_id 1, foo_id 2 and parent_foo_id 5. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT foo_id FROM foo
    WHERE fk_id = 100
    UNION
    SELECT foo_id FROM foo f
    JOIN foo_combo c ON f.foo_id = c.parent_foo_id
    WHERE fk_id = 100
    UNION
    SELECT foo_id FROM foo f
    JOIN foo_combo c ON f.foo_id = c.parent_foo_id
    WHERE fk_id = 100) as ids
JOIN foo USING(foo_id);
```